# Infinite sums of squares

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, telescopic-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {k^2(1-k)^2}{(n+k)^2(n+1-k)^2}$$
Here can anyone help me to solve this question,I can't think of any logic like telescopic, coefficient compare etc .
It would be helpful if anyone could provide the solution

Comment: Please don't use pictures, use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Note the terms in the numerator are independent of $n$...those can simply be pulled out of the sum.

Comment: Note also that you need restrictions on $k$ to ensure that the terms are never singular (or you could simply delete the singular terms).

Comment: The series diverges for integer $k$, Assuming $k \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, the series sums to $$\frac{k^2(1-k)^2}{(1-2k)^2}\left[\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi k)} - \frac{2\pi\cot(\pi k)}{1-2k}\right]$$

Answer (score 2):

The series diverges for integer $k$, Assuming $k \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, the series sums to $$\frac{k^2(1-k)^2}{(1-2k)^2}\left[\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi k)} - \frac{2\pi\cot(\pi k)}{1-2k}\right]\tag{*1}$$

Let $\alpha = k$ and $\beta = 1 - k$, the sum at hand equals to

$$\begin{align}\verb/sum/ 
&= \alpha^2\beta^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+\alpha)^2(n+\beta)^2}\\
&= \frac{\alpha^2\beta^2}{(\alpha-\beta)^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n+\alpha} - \frac{1}{n+\beta}\right)^2\\
&= \frac{\alpha^2\beta^2}{(\alpha-\beta)^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(n+\alpha)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+\beta)^2} - \frac{2}{(n+\alpha)(n+\beta)}\right)\\
&= \frac{\alpha^2\beta^2}{(\alpha-\beta)^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{(n+\alpha)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+\beta)^2} - \frac{2}{\beta - \alpha}\left(\frac{1}{n+\alpha} - \frac{1}{n+\beta}\right)\right]
\end{align}
$$
The four pieces inside above bracket can be combined into two pieces

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(n+\alpha)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+\beta)^2}\right)
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(n+k)^2} + \frac{1}{(-(n+1)+k)^2}\right) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}$$
and
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n+\alpha} - \frac{1}{n+\beta}\right)
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n+k} + \frac{1}{-(n+1)+k}\right) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}$$
where sums of the form $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty (\cdots)$ is a short hand for the symmetric limit $\lim\limits_{p\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=-p}^p (\cdots)$

Using following [Mittag-Leffler expansion for cotangent](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_Expansion_for_Cotangent_Function) and its derivative, $(*1)$ follows immediately.

$$\pi \cot(\pi x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x + n}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi x)} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(x+n)^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica gives the following result:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^2 (1-k)^2}{(n+k)^2 (n+1-k)^2}=\frac{k^2 (1-k)^2 \left(\pi \csc^2(\pi k) (\pi (2 k-1)+\sin(2 \pi k))\right)}{(2 k-1)^3}\ ,$$ $$\Im(k)\neq 0\lor 0<k<1\lor k\notin \mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 1):

I thought it would be instructive to present a way forward using contour integration.  To that end we now proceed.

---

Let $f(z)=\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{(z+k)^2(z+1-k)^2}$ and let $N\ge \max(|k|, |k-1|)$.  Then, we see that

$$\begin{align}\oint_{|z|=N+1/2}f(z)\,dz&=2\pi i \left(\text{Res}\left(f(z), z=-k\right)+\text{Res}\left(f(z), z=k-1\right)+\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \text{Res}\left(f(z), z=n\right)\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \left(\text{Res}\left(f(z), z=-k\right)+\text{Res}\left(f(z), z=k-1\right)+ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi(n+k)^2(n+1-k)^2}\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \left(\text{Res}\left(f(z), z=-k\right)+\text{Res}\left(f(z), z=k-1\right)+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi(n+k)^2(n+1-k)^2}\right)\tag1
\end{align}$$

Note that $|\cot(\pi z)|$ is bounded on the circle $|z|=N+1/2$.  Then, letting $N\to \infty$ in $(1)$, we find that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+k)^2(n+1-k)^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(-\text{Res}\left(f(z), z=-k\right)-\text{Res}\left(f(z), z=k-1\right)\right)\tag2$$

---

The residues in $(2)$ are given by

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(f(z), z=-k\right)&=\lim_{z\to -k}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{(z+1-k)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{-\pi \csc^2(\pi k)}{(2k-1)^2}-2\frac{\cot(k\pi)}{(2k-1)^3}\tag{3a}\\\\
\text{Res}\left(f(z), z=k-1\right)&=\frac{-\pi \csc^2(\pi k)}{(2k-1)^2}+2\frac{\cot(k\pi)}{(2k-1)^3}\tag{3b}
\end{align}$$

---

Using $(3a)$ and $(3b)$ reveals that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(n+k)^2(n+1-k)^2}=\frac{\pi^2 \csc^2(\pi k)}{(2k-1)^2}-\frac{2\pi \cot(\pi k)}{(2k-1)^3}\tag4$$

whereupon multuplying $(4)$ by $k^2(1-k)^2)$ yields the coveted result.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Hi Oliver.  How are you?  It's great to hear from you!  I check MSE from time to time, but most of the questions are in areas of math that either I don't find of interest, don't have the requisite knowledge to contribute a worthy answer, or both.  Who are the "Vogons from CURED?"  Some of the newer MSE moderators have extreme views as to what constitutes a quality question.  I wonder if their extremist views have resulted in the markedly decreased numbers of questions that I find of interest.

Comment: I will not name names, but tit is clear that the many of their frequent participants (you can see their site in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com) communities are very militant and organized. I see a parallel with Republican Party (CURED and their supporters) which is a highly organize lot that have now control of the Supreme Court (Moderators)  with highly partisan justices. Veteran moderators in our community at some point will stand out (actuarial reasons) and will be replaced by ... well a spiral of death. This is my opinion.

Comment: Yes, some of the MSE participants are militant and have begun to overthrow the old regime.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $k$ is an integer:

1. From the $n+k$ in the denominator it follows that $k \geqslant 1$ because otherwise one summand is undefined.
2. From the $n+1-k$ in the denominator it follows that $1-k \geqslant 1$ because otherwise one summand is undefined.

Not much that's left for $k$...

Answer (score 0):

(I don't see an equation, just an expression?) Convert the expression into partial fractions

$
...= \frac{2k^2(1-2k+k^2)}{(-1+2k)^3} \frac{1}{n+k}-\frac{2k^2(1-2k+k^2)}{(-1+2k)^3} \frac{1}{n+1-k}+\frac{k^2(1-2k+k^2)}{(-1+2k)^2}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}+
\frac{k^2(1-2k+k^2)}{(-1+2k)^2}\frac{1}{(n+1-k)^2}
$

and the result can be written as a sum over $\psi(k)$,
$\psi(1-k)$ and its derivatives.